# How can I make this logo responsive? CSS isn't working on the logo

Tags: css, responsive-design, graphical-logo

I've tried a few different ways of writing the CSS and this is the closest I get, but I can't get the logo to shrink down to a reasonable size compared to the rest of the jumbotron. If you shrink the screen down to the size of a phone or so, the logo looks huge. I resized the photo so it should stay at most 150px. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta description="">
    <meta keywords="">
    <title>Jan Clark Studio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Courgette&family=EB+Garamond:ital@0;1&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <center>
            <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" style="background-color:#487C84">
            <div class="title">
            <div class="d-inline-flex">
                <img src="Photos/Three%20Trees%20001.png" class="img-fluid">
                <h1>Jan Clark Studio</h1>
            </div>
            </div>
                <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="indexphoto">
                <img src="Photos/American%20Kestral%20-%20Looking%20For%20A%20Piece%20Of%20The%20Action%20%20--Watercolor%20by%20Jan%20Clark%20-%20use.JPG" class="img-fluid" max-width="100%" max-height="auto">
                <h3><p>American Kestral - Looking for a Piece of the Action</p></h3>
                <h5><p><i>Watercolor</i></p></h5>
            </div>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
div.title img {
width: 100%;
max-width: 150px;
height: auto;
float: left;
margin-right: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: This might be a good use case for [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use VW instead of PX or whatever.
`width: 100%` is not needed if you want responsible img, and having max `width: 150px;` at the same time means that it will be always 150px
You can use `max-width: 150px;` and `width: 10vw;` ([the width of the viewport*](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)); and set min-width:(whatever you want, to don't make your img very almost invisible, if you resize more and more)
Here's example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v1kxpem8/)

Comment: You can use @media queries
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Using a max and min width with the width: 10vw; worked! Thank you so much!